# Is it safe to attach an event listener to $(document) before DOM ready?

Tags: jquery, dom

Is the following code safe? Will `document` be available?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).delegate(".my-class", "click", function() { /* do something here */ } );
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, if `document` weren't available you couldn't do `$( document ).ready()` either...

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

Comment: Superseded, but not depreciated.

Comment: @j08691 Yes but you can still use it and keep using it, it will never be deprecated

Comment: @Esailija - never say never. Kevin B - I never said it was deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is completely safe. The `document` always exists.